# Удалить все четные числа

Tags: c++, файлы

Дан текстовый файл, содержащий целые числа. Удалить из него все четные числа.

Comment: Очень хорошее учебное задание. А нас вы что хотели спросить?

Comment: Как преобразовать строковый массив(который я получил из файла) в числовой, чтобы вытянуть из него все нечетные ?

Comment: @ІлайБендер Вы имеет в виду массив с элементами типа std::string или char[]?

Comment: @ІлайБендер Покажите в своем вопросе хотя бы как вы читаете файл в массив.

Comment: char buffer[50];
 ifstream fin("i.txt");
 fin.getline(buffer, 50);
 fin.close();
 cout << buffer;

И дальше ступор

Comment: @ІлайБендер дополните свой вопрос кодом, который у вас уже есть.

Answer (score 2):

Удалить все четные числа из строки можно следующим образом, как показано в ниже приведенной демонстрационной программе.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

int main() 
{
    char s[] = "0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9";

    std::cout << s << std::endl;

    std::istringstream is( s );
    std::ostringstream os;

    std::copy_if( std::istream_iterator<int>( is ),
                  std::istream_iterator<int>(),
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>( os, " " ),
                  []( int x ) { return x % 2; } );

    std::strcpy( s, os.str().c_str() );

    std::cout << s << std::endl;



    return 0;
}
```

Вывод на консоль будет следующим

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
1 3 5 7 9
```

Comment: `std::istream_iterator<int>` а нельзя как-то сократить?) или только тип свой объявить?

Comment: @pavel Можно ввести алиас для этого типа либо используя typedef либо using конструкции.

Comment: ну это понятно, я думал может как-то `auto` можно применить...

Comment: @pavel Чтобы применить auto, нужно инициализирующее выражение, которое имеет тот же тип, что и объявляемый объект.

Comment: @pavel можно второй аргумент заменить на `{}`

Answer (score 1):

src.src

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

log.log

```
 1  3  5  7  9
```

файл для [f]lex

```
%option noyywrap main
%%
[0-9]+      { int N = atoi(yytext); if (N % 2 == 1) printf(yytext); }
```

Makefile

```
log.log: src.src ./exe.exe
    ./exe.exe < $< > $@ && tail $@
C = lex.yy.c
./exe.exe: $(C)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $(C)
lex.yy.c: lpp.lpp
    flex $<
```

Связка **flex/bison (lex/yacc) -- богатейший хинт для ввода любых текстовых данных**, по сравнению с ним ни один язык программирования (кроме разве что perlа) вообще не содержит средств ввода данных 8-).

Comment: +1 за остроумное использование flex, но всё же автор вопроса хотел решение на C++